# Why is the hash of a hash different from the hash

Tags: python, hash

You read the question right.  Here's my example.

```
 [in] >>> item = ('y', 4)
 [in] >>> hash(item)
[out] >>> -8853662433461058885
 [in] >>> hash(hash(item))
[out] >>> -1936133405819977032
```

In Python hashes are integers.  Most integers with a reasonably small absolute value have trivial hash functions

```
 [in] >>> hash(3)
[out] >>> 3
```

I understand that some integers that are arbitrarily large will eventually hash to a different, probably smaller number.  For example:

```
 [in] >>> pi = 314159265358979323846264338327950
 [in] >>> hash(pi)
[out] >>> 423427704026669588
```

I would have assumed that the output of any hash function would be a small enough integer so that when that integer itself was hashed, it would return itself as a value.  That's to say hash(hash(x)) == hash(x).  Why is this not always the case?

Comment: I see that the crossover points are +(2^61 - 1) and -(2^61 - 2).  64 bits of data.  Fine.  What I'm confused by is why the hash functions for other builtin types don't return numbers that are within that range.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in hash() method is only meant for comparing dictionary keys.

From the [python documentation](http://Return%20the%20hash%20value%20of%20the%20object%20(if%20it%20has%20one).%20Hash%20values%20are%20integers.%20They%20are%20used%20to%20quickly%20compare%20dictionary%20keys%20during%20a%20dictionary%20lookup.%20Numeric%20values%20that%20compare%20equal%20have%20the%20same%20hash%20value%20(even%20if%20they%20are%20of%20different%20types,%20as%20is%20the%20case%20for%201%20and%201.0).) for `hash()`:

> They are used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary
>   lookup. Numeric values that compare equal have the same hash value
>   (even if they are of different types, as is the case for 1 and 1.0).

If you need a hash that works across sytems, use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html).

Comment: The built in hash is also used for sets/frozensets, which may be splitting hairs, considering that sets are simply amputated dictionaries at the C level anyway.